# Declare methods with pointer outside class in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I want to declare the methods of the following code outside the class but i get the following error whenever the method is a pointer to private member variable:
"no instance of function template "std::next" matches the required typeC/C++(386)".

```
class Node
{

private:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node() {}

    int GetData() { return data; }
    Node *GetNext() { return next; }

    void SetData(int aData) { data = aData; }
    void SetNext(Node *aNext) { next = aNext; }
};

// outside try class declaration of
int Node::GetData() { return data; }
Node Node::*GetNext() { return next; } // here is the error!!
```

Would you help me?

Comment: You should do `Node* Node::getNext()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wrong

```
Node Node::*GetNext() { return next; }
```

This is right

```
Node* Node::GetNext() { return next; }
```

The name of function is `Node::GetNext` and not `GetNext`.

Comment: How do i declare the following inside class setter??
.
.
 void SetNext(Node *aNext) { next = aNext; }?

Comment: @zumuha Ask one question per question please.

Comment: btw. that's one argument for putting the asterisk on the type instead of the name...

Comment: @StefanRiedel one could argue the name is `Node::getNext`

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore and I wouldn't disagree, but the point still stands: if you had put the asterisk on the type (because it IS part of the returned type) this confusion wouldn't have arised. But as I said, that's just my opinion on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

You must put the asterisk after the return type because the return type is a pointer to Node object

like this:

```cpp
Node *Node::GetNext() { return next; }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write `Node *GetNext();`, this means the method name is `GetNext` and the return type is `Node *`. It doesn't matter whether you put the asterisk near the method name or away from it.

Outside of the class, you need fully qualified name of the method which is `Node::GetNext` with return type `Node *`. So it would look like `Node *Node::GetNext();` or `Node* Node::GetNext();` depending on your style of the placement of the asterisk.

Comment: Thank you @debashish.ghosh.